# Is there any SQL support in Vertica/MySQL for linear algebra calculations?

Tags: mysql, sql, vertica

My data is already in Vertica and MySQL.
I need to calculate many linear algebra related calculations - cross products, matrix multiplications and some other related calculations you can easily perform in numpy for instance.

The SQL code for this task became very complicated, slow, long and hard to read.

Is there any SQL support in Vertica/MySQL for such task ?
anything similar to numpy ?
or it is necessary in such case to use UDF that calls functions that are using numpy?

Comment: Check out this url - please - https://datavirtuality.com/connectors/integrate/mysql/vertica/

Comment: If you talk cross products and matrix multiplications - if you need them, you will invariably have a cpu, memory, and disk intensive process, whatever you use. I once had to cross join a multi-billion row of telemetric data (1000s per second, dozens of machines, 15 years' worth of data) with itself - to calculate a similarity comparison of a 30-second sensor data curve with the existing data  - using Euclidean distance over that 30-second-period.

Comment: It did take some 3 minutes, with well designed tables - but then it had been completely impossible before. Use SQL as far as you can, design your tables well, physically, then use existing ML functions, and finally import Python libraries into the cluster, and develop your own User Defined Extensions in Python. I'm convinced it will be the simplest to read (all in one place) and the fastest version